# MongoDB extracting values from BasicDBObject (Java)

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

I am having trouble retrieving values from queried documents in MongoDB.

For example, the doc structure is like:

```
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "50f93b74f9eccc540b302462"
        },
       "response": {
            "result": {
                "code": "1000",
                "msg": "Command completed successfully"
            },
            "resData": {
                "domain:infData": {
                    "domain:name": "ritesh.com",
                    "domain:crDate": "2007-06-15T12:02:36.0000Z",
                    "domain:exDate": "2013-06-15T12:02:36.0000Z"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the query code is:

```
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("domains");

    BasicDBObject p = new BasicDBObject("response.resData.domain:infData.domain:name", "ritesh.com");
    DBCursor c = collection.find(p);

    while(c.hasNext()) {
        DBObject obj = c.next();
        Object value = obj.get("response.resData.domain:infData.domain:name");
    }
```

It queries fine and fetches the doc, but I can't seem to figure out how to extract the value of "response.resData.domain:infData.domain:name" or other similarly nested values from the DBObject (or BasicDBObject since c.next() returns type BasicDBObject).

I could fetch the objects one at a time like:

```
    ((DBObject)obj.get("response")).get("resData")....
```

but that seems very cumbersome.

I thought since you can put() a nested field value in BasicDBObject like:

```
    basicDBObject.put("response.resData.domain:infData.domain:name", "ritesh.com");
```

that I could similarly use get() to fetch from the BasicDBObject result using the same kind of key. Like I attempted to do in the code above with:

```
    Object value = obj.get("response.resData.domain:infData.domain:name");
```

But that is returning a null value.

It's probably something straightforward, but I can't seem to figure it out. And everywhere I've checked on the net the examples only fetch values that aren't nested, from the result. Like

```
    doc.get("name");
```

instead of something like:

```
    doc.get("name.lastname.clanname");
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

There's no way to chain a property name like you're doing using the Java driver (`get`s for sure, and according to the [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-151), `put` isn't supposed to work either).

You'll need to get the objects one at a time like you suggested.

```
((DBObject)obj.get("response")).get("resData")
```

See [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-260?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) for a potential future feature that would allow your syntax to possibly work (although, likely with a new method name).

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem and I wrote a small function to fetch chained properties.

```
private Object getFieldFromCursor(DBObject o, String fieldName) {

    final String[] fieldParts = StringUtils.split(fieldName, '.');

    int i = 1;
    Object val = o.get(fieldParts[0]);

    while(i < fieldParts.length && val instanceof DBObject) {
        val = ((DBObject)val).get(fieldParts[i]);
        i++;
    }

    return val;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: You could use `fieldName.split("\\.")` to not depend on StringUtils