# cursor.next() always returns "java.util.NoSuchElementException"

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, pymongo

I am writing a program in java which reads query results from MongoDB.

Below is the code (which gives an exception):

```
if(output != null){
                BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
                DBCursor cursor = null;
                for (DBObject obj : output.results()) {
                    String UserID = obj.get("UserID").toString();
                    whereQuery.put("User_ID", UserID);                                                              

                    cursor = users.find(whereQuery);
                    System.out.println(cursor.toString());
                    System.out.println("This user name who tweeted "+ cursor.next());


                }
            }
```

When I run this code, only the first value of cursor gets printed using the sysout statement in the last line, the second value which comes from the 'for' loop results in an exception. Wonder why?

The sysout statement just before the cursor.next() prints the current value in the cursor all the time, placed it there to verify whether the cursor actually has a value.

I have tried the hasNext() while loop for the cursor.next(), it only enters the loop for the first time the rest of the checks it just jumps out.

```
Error stack trace:
   Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
   at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.next(QueryResultIterator.java:111)
   at com.mongodb.DBCursor._next(DBCursor.java:510)
   at com.mongodb.DBCursor.next(DBCursor.java:581)
   at ReadData.referencedDataModel(ReadData.java:97)
   at ReadData.main(ReadData.java:131)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure its your answer, but it's worth a try:

```
String UserID = obj.get("UserID").toString();
cursor = users.find(whereQuery);
if(cursor.hasNext()) {
    // the object will be your object, its basically a json document
    BasicDBObject obj = cursor.next(); 

    // print obj to console as json file
    System.out.println(obj);

    // you can get any property with obj.get...(); method such as .getString()
    // The below code will extract the User_ID from the object you received via find query 
    string id = obj.getString("User_ID");
}
```

If you are sure the result will have just one document you can use this code:

```
BasicDBObject obj = users.findOne(whereQuery);
```

Very useful resource about java and Mongo:

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/

Comment: This is new stuff to me! I was under the impression that cursor = users.find(whereQuery); would always give the cursor a document to iterate over.

Comment: It doesn't solve my issue though. The check if(cursor.hasNext()) exits after the second check. The first check is always successful.

Comment: It exits because you have just one item in your cursor. for retrieve id use this inside of loop. BasicDBObject obj = cursor.next(); string id = obj.getString("User_ID");

Comment: Can you edit your answer with the modifications and in accordance with my code in the question?

Comment: @Raks-Men. I'm not sure what exactly you want, but the answer updated

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from DBCursor to BasicDBObject: "BasicDBObject obj = users.find(whereQuery);" same for BasicDBObject obj = cursor.next(); and I am not getting why obj is getting assigned again. The obj is coming from the for loop "for (DBObject obj : output.results())"

Comment: Oh oh, obj is not assigned again, that was another solution, you should use way1 or way2. if you are sure the query result just one document use way2(BasicDBObject obj = users.findOne(whereQuery);)

Comment: The findOne returns a DBObject object..and there is type mismatch for BasicDBObject and even if I use DBObject obj = users.findOne(whereQuery); obj.get..() does not work, for 'obj' being a DBObject.

Comment: If (DBObject)obj.get("User_ID")) is not working I have no clue about your problem. good link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410531/mongodb-extracting-values-from-basicdbobject-java

Comment: Thanks, is there any way I can reset the cursor? Doesn't cursor = users.find(whereQuery); put a new value in cursor eachtime the loop goes over it?

Comment: No, you cant put new value in cursor, you have to do a new query. and when you iterate all objects in cursor, the cursor will be close automatically. just as info: cursor is read-only

Comment: Okay, cannot find a single place on the internet where the DBcursor is within a for loop or so. ;{

Answer (score 1):

```
if(output != null){
                BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
                DBCursor cursor;

                for (DBObject obj : output.results()) {

                    String UserID = obj.get("UserID").toString();
                    System.out.println("The real results "+ UserID);

                    whereQuery.put("User_ID", UserID);                                                  
                    DBObject value = users.findOne(whereQuery);
                    if(value != null)
                        System.out.println("The user who used the word in the tweet: " +value.get("User_Name").toString());
                    else
                        System.out.println("The user profile is not available");
                }

            }
```

Screw cursors!

Thanks @Disposer!