# Java code to print keys and values from nested document in mongo

Tags: java, mongodb

For a mongo database which has the following details:

```
[{
    "Name" : "Krishna",
    "Fruits" : {
    "Apples" : 5,
    "Oranges" : 10
    }
},
{
    "Name" : "Kiran",
    "Fruits" : {
    "Plums" : 10,
    "Watermelons" : 1
    }
}]
```

I want to print the following output:

```
Krishna has 5 Apples, 10 Oranges

Kiran has 10 Plums, 1 Watermelons
```

Following is the snippet of code I wrote.  Please help me in filling up the blanks.  Please note that there is no limit on the kind of fruits that the user can have.

```
try {
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
    MongoCollection < Document > collection = database.getCollection("inventory");
    MongoCursor < Document > cursor = collection.find().iterator();
    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            Document doc = cursor.next();
            String name = doc.getString("Name"));
            //TODO: Fill inventory
            String inventory =

        System.out.println(name + " has " + inventory);
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
} catch (MongoException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Accept the solution proposed by Igor

Comment: What did you try so far? What is your specific question/problem?

Comment: I know how to query if i know the key.  But in this case, i dont know what keys to expect and the keys are in a nested document: Fruits

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB extracting values from BasicDBObject (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410531/mongodb-extracting-values-from-basicdbobject-java)

Comment: Probably my question is not understood properly. (1) I just want to access the inner document which is under "Fruits" (2) I want to iterate over all the keys in that document since i dont know what keys are present inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way that you can do:

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = (Map) document.get("Fruits");
    Iterator iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
    String inventory = " ";
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = iterator.next().toString();
        int value = map.get(key);
        inventory += value + " " + key;
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            inventory += ", ";
        } else {
            inventory += ".";
        }
    }
```

This should be work but casting is not recommended thing, so better check this link and figure out how to avoid it with BsonReader:
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/bson/readers-and-writers/